# Prime Number Theory (Dividers)

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

When $N = a^\alpha × b^β × c^γ$ is divided by $a$, the number of dividers decreases by $m$ units; when divided by $b$, decreases by $n$ and, dividing by $c$, decreases by $p$. Determine the exponents $α, β$ and $γ$.

Mine ended up giving in this system here:
$$
(α-a)(β+1)(γ+1)-(γ+1)(β+1) = (α+1)(β+1)(γ+1)-m; 
(β-b)(α+1)(γ+1)-(γ+1)(α+1) = (α+1)(β+1)(γ+1)-n;
(γ-b)(α+1)(β+1)-(α+1)(β+1) = (α+1)(β+1)(γ+1)-p
$$

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ distinct primes? If so, the number of divisors of $N/a$ is $\alpha(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)$, and so on.

Comment: This is just the same, sorry if you didn't specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $N = a^\alpha \times b^{\beta} \times c^{\gamma}$ is divided by $a$, it becomes $\frac{N}{a} = a^{\alpha - 1} \times b^{\beta} \times c^{\gamma}$. Thus, as [metamorphy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/543769/metamorphy)'s question comment indicates that if we can assume $a$, $b$ and $c$ are distinct primes, then since the number of divisors decreases by $m$, this means that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(\alpha - 1 + 1)(\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) & = (\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) - m \\
(\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) - (\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) & = (\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) - m \\
- (\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) & = -m \\
(\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) & = m
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Similarly, we also have

$$(\alpha + 1)(\gamma + 1) = n \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$(\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1) = p \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Multiplying \eqref{eq1A}, \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} together gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left((\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1)\right)^2 & = mnp \\
(\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)(\gamma + 1) & = \sqrt{mnp}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Dividing \eqref{eq4A} by \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\alpha + 1 & = \frac{\sqrt{mnp}}{m} \\
\alpha & = \sqrt{\frac{np}{m}} - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Similarly, you can also get that

$$\beta = \sqrt{\frac{mp}{n}} - 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

$$\gamma = \sqrt{\frac{mn}{p}} - 1 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Comment: Wouldn't this '' b '' be '' n ''?